# Laravel ORM Отношения таблиц Words и Synonyms

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Задача (идея):

Создать таблицу `words` и хранить в нем слова. Структура:

```
words:
- id
- value
```

Создать таблицу `synonyms`. Структура:

```
synonyms:
- id
- word_id // Чтобы не дублировать слова, брать значение из таблицы words
```

Создать таблицу `synonym_word`, для отношения типа `ManyToMany`. Структура:

```
synonyms_word: 
- synonym_id
- word_id
```

Но мне кажется, что я совсем неправильно мыслю и делаю.

Вопрос: Как организовать структуру таблиц и связей, чтобы в таблице `words` хранить слова, и иметь возможность получить доступ ко всем `synonyms` синонимам слов, а также сам синоним это ссылка на слово из таблицы `words`?

P.S. Мысль изложить внятно, наверно, не получилось)

Comment: Я бы не делал промежуточную таблицу synonyms, а в таблице synonym_word в качестве id'шников указывал разные id из таблицы words при этом связь будет таже

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ:**
Вам нужно создать таблицу words, которая будет содержать сами слова, туда же заносить синонимы (было бы странно, если бы вы хранили какие-то "определённые" слова в таблице words, а их синонимы в другой таблице, мне кажется это глупо, ведь и то, и то просто слова), структура таблицы:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->string('title');
$table->bigIncrements('synonym_id');
```

Поле `synonym_id` общее для всех слов с одинаковым смыслом (синонимов), далее, всё что вам нужно будет, это заполнить таблицу словами и выводить по запросу определённого слова, все слова где совпадает synonym_id.

Вывод реализуется в методе index ([CRUD](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial)), что-то подобное:

```
public function index ($synonym_id) {
    $synonyms = get()->all()->where('synonym_id', $synonym_id);
    return view('synonyms.index', compact('synonyms'));
}
```

Comment: А если у слова не один синоним?

Comment: @Walfter       То в чём проблема?? Создаётся поле synonym_id в котором для всех синонимов одинаковое значение и после обращения к конкретному слову по его первичному ключу, вызываем все слова у которых совпадает synonym_id.

Comment: Например у слова Смелый есть синоним Храбрый.... У слова Отважный есть синоним Храбрый.... То как слову Храбрый присвоить два разных synonym_id

Comment: @Waltfter      создать условие, которое будет описывать логику выборки.

Comment: Приведите пример

Answer (score 0):

если у слова есть много синонимов а у синонима только одно слово то (как верно заметили в комментариях) третья таблиц лишняя. Отношение один ко многим, плюс во вторую таблицу добавить колонку со значениями синонимов

```
synonyms:
- id
- word_id
- value
```

В модели отношение

```
public function synonyms()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Synonym');
}
```